# javacl - pass int2* (or any generic buffer of vectors ) to the kernel

Tags: java, opencl

Writing some code to study openCL through javaCL binding, I arrived to the point where I had to pass a buffer of int2 ( __global int2* seeds ) to the kernel, but i Couldn't find the way to do it in javaCL because the context object doesn't provide any createInt2Buffer or analog method to create a [generic_vector_type]Buffer.

As a workaround I rewrote the kernel to accept two buffers of int, but of course the problem remains.

So, is there something that I am missing or this feature is not yet implemented by the library?

Comment: If you found the solution, please post it as your answer.

Comment: @geotavros: the solution is indeed in my first edit of the post, dated April 13

Comment: ok, but here people post their solution in answer section and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per request I post my answer:

Found the solution in code example from the author of the library blog. The int2* opencl buffer is not mapped as int[n][2] in javacl, but as int[n*2] where the elements n.x and n.y are interleaved

```
n.x-> array[n*2];
n.y-> array[n*2+1];
```